# Passing precision as parameter to python format

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, string-formatting

I want to format a float with the precision as parameter

```
"{0:,.2f}$".format(1000 + 1/float(3))
'1,000.33$'
```

How can I pass the number of decimal places (`.2f`) as parameter ?

Just for reference, I know I can use `round(n,precision)` but then when `precision=0` it prints `0.0` which is not what I want. I can also concatenate like `"{0:,." + str(precision) + "2f}f".format(n)` but you know ...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can nest the format fields to dynamically specify the precision:

```
>>> "{1:,.{0}f}$".format(2, 1000 + 1/float(3))
'1,000.33$'
>>>
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings):

> A `format_spec` field can also include nested replacement fields within
>   it. These nested replacement fields can contain only a field name;
>   conversion flags and format specifications are not allowed. The
>   replacement fields within the `format_spec` are substituted before the
>   `format_spec` string is interpreted. This allows the formatting of a
>   value to be dynamically specified.

Comment: Thanks. So basically the solution is to move the concatenation of `'.' + str(precision) + 'f'`  from the actual format to a parameter ? This does not feel right.

Comment: OK. got it, `"{1:,.{0}f}$".format(2, 1000 + 1/float(3))`

Comment: Yea, that is right.  Your question said how to put `.2f` in the string, so I went with that originally.  I updated my answer to what you actually wanted.

Comment: I suggest having the word 'within' in the answer bolded or written in italics so that it is somehow highlighted, as it is important to note that the most inner field is first substituted.